# How to use awaitable inside async?

Tags: f#

I'm fairly new to F# and as practice I'm currently writing a module that has a lot of interop with C# libraries.

When library code returns me `Task`, it's not a problem - I already found a package that enables `let!` with tasks.

Right now I'm using [cliwrap](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/CliWrap) and its `ExecuteAsync()` method returns not a `Task`, but some other awaitable type(you can `await` it in C# and it has `GetAwaiter()` method).

So far I came up with the following code to use it(please ignore usage of `test` and `()`, its temprorary for debugging):

```
 let testLaunchDelayed = async {
                        let cmd = Cli.Wrap(@"C:\Launcher\Launcher.exe").WithArguments("--TestName " + testName)
                        let test = cmd.ExecuteAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()
                        ()
                    }
                    Async.StartImmediate testLaunchDelayed
```

It seems to work, but using `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` feels wrong. Is there a better way ?

**Update**
Tried using `taskbuilder`, ended up with this:

```
async {
      let cmd = Cli.Wrap(@"C:\Test\git\tests\func\nunit\AllBin\publish_win10-x64\CommonTestLauncher.exe").WithArguments("--TestName " + testName);
      let! cmdTask = task{return! cmd.ExecuteAsync()}
      ()
}
```

Comment: [Ply](https://github.com/crowded/ply) and [TaskBuilder](https://github.com/rspeele/TaskBuilder.fs/blob/master/TaskBuilder.fs) both supports awaitable, not just task. What library do you use?

Comment: @JL0PD updated question. Is it correct, or is there an easier way to get result from awaitable?

Comment: `CommandTask` has a property called `Task` that returns a regular task. You can use that to convert to async.

Answer (score 3):

The issue with using `GetResult` is that this is a synchronous blocking call. Ideally, you want to use the `OnCompleted` event to get notified when the operation completes and, only then, access the result. You can encapsulate this into a helper `awaitAwaiter`, which is much like the `Async.AwaitTask` operation:

```
let awaitAwaiter (a:Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter<_>) = 
  Async.FromContinuations(fun (cont, econt, ccont) ->
    a.OnCompleted(fun () -> 
      let res = 
        try Choice1Of3 (a.GetResult())
        with 
        | :? System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException as ce -> Choice2Of3 ce
        | e -> Choice3Of3 e 
      match res with 
      | Choice1Of3 res -> cont res
      | Choice2Of3 ce -> ccont (OperationCanceledException("Task has been cancelled", ce))
      | Choice3Of3 e -> econt e ) )
```

This uses `FromContinuations` to create a new asynchronous computation that uses `OnCompleted` to get notified when the work is done and then triggers appropriate continuation (handling errors - hopefully correctly, but I have not tested this!)

The use is the same as with `AwaitTask`:

```
let testLaunchDelayed testName = async {
  let cmd = Cli.Wrap(@"C:\Launcher\Launcher.exe").WithArguments("--TestName " + testName)
  let test = cmd.ExecuteAsync().GetAwaiter() |> awaitAwaiter
  () }
```